# Solidworks gear representation in drawing

Tags: solidworks

I have an assembly in Solidworks with gears that I want to make a sketch from it.
I want to hide the gears teeth and represent the each gear teeth only as center line, like in the picture below on the left:[image: Taken as an example from https://www.cad-notes.com/automate-standard-additional-notes-in-the-drawing/amp/]

I have tried every button in Solidworks, but didn't find how to hide the unnecessary tooth at the end.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could make a configuration of the component with the teeth suppressed and the OD adjusted to the centreline

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it, but I've been told that there is a button for it, I guess the person lied to me.